# How do I customise the colours of the groups and overlay a contour with values over an NMDS ordination spider graph plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I've ran an NMDS using `vegan` on some ecological data showing species frequency and habitat types and produced a spider graph plot showing the differences between the groups(habitats) using some code I found.
I'd like to be able to change the colours of the habitats to represent a gradient from one main habitat to the next and add a contour over the top showing the change in Shannon diversity using `ordisurf` with figures on the contours.

Here is some example data (apologies if this is too large of a subset) named `dataNMDS`.

```
structure(list(Plot_ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
    Plot_gradient = c("Grassland", "Grassland", "Grassland", 
    "EGA", "EGA", "EGA", "EGB", "EGB", "EGB", "EGC", "EGC", "EGC", 
    "EHC", "EHC", "EHC", "EHB", "EHB", "EHB", "EHA", "EHA", "EHA", 
    "Heath", "Heath", "Heath"), SSD_stdev = c(6.475059845, 7.730873172, 
    5.451752012, 1.854723699, 3.847076812, 1.939071943, 3.382306905, 
    2.332380758, 1.673320053, 2.481934729, 4.955804677, 1.624807681, 
    3.2, 6.337191807, 0.748331477, 0.632455532, 3.521363372, 
    0.8, 1.264911064, 9.583318841, 0.748331477, 1.977473135, 
    6.66765326, 3.404937591), log_mean = c(3.77, 3.77, 3.68, 
    3.65, 3.68, 3.41, 3.64, 3.8, 3.4, 3.65, 3.72, 3.43, 3.65, 
    3.73, 3.36, 3.57, 3.88, 3.38, 3.6, 3.79, 3.38, 3.84, 3.53, 
    3.3), conductivity = c(770L, 555L, 508L, 508L, 553L, 532L, 
    605L, 443L, 454L, 561L, 533L, 554L, 502L, 435L, 523L, 452L, 
    384L, 494L, 502L, 411L, 378L, 461L, 507L, 383L), percentage_c = c(32.144, 
    28.316, 31.498, 9.612, 21.184, 20.764, 14.819, 21.187, 16.619, 
    19.554, 28.565, 23.694, 7.539, 14.12, 23.769, 9.696, 13.022, 
    18.966, 10.053, 15.969, 12.395, 6.013, 17.848, 10.716), percentage_n = c(2.398, 
    2.224, 2.321, 0.799, 1.798, 1.497, 1.192, 1.875, 1.091, 1.618, 
    2.149, 1.679, 0.557, 1.172, 1.361, 0.679, 1.121, 1.325, 0.715, 
    1.368, 0.83, 0.465, 1.394, 0.734), percentage_ic = c(0.047, 
    0.049, 0.046, 0.048, 0.049, 0.048, 0.049, 0.048, 0.05, 0.051, 
    0.048, 0.047, 0.049, 0.051, 0.048, 0.05, 0.048, 0.047, 0.051, 
    0.046, 0.05, 0.05, 0.046, 0.05), Racomitrium_lanuginosum = c(2.4, 
    11.2, 3.2, 52, 32, 24, 16, 40, 0, 48, 0, 16, 88, 8, 100, 
    96, 76, 64, 100, 40, 68, 71, 57, 74), Vaccinium_myrtillus = c(2.4, 
    22.4, 9.6, 28, 24, 20, 32, 20, 28, 16, 44, 60, 52, 52, 44, 
    28, 16, 16, 16, 52, 48, 34.5, 18.5, 48), Agrostis_capillaris = c(37.6, 
    54.4, 11.2, 60, 64, 16, 96, 36, 16, 68, 44, 24, 88, 76, 84, 
    92, 92, 0, 68, 76, 88, 57.5, 35.5, 16.5), Galium_saxatile = c(0.8, 
    24, 18.4, 4, 12, 24, 32, 24, 4, 4, 24, 8, 4, 44, 56, 48, 
    56, 4, 0, 36, 52, 15.5, 23.5, 11.5), Carex_pilulifera = c(31.2, 
    15.2, 25.6, 24, 0, 76, 0, 20, 92, 24, 0, 80, 4, 0, 12, 0, 
    0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Festuca_ovina = c(0, 1.6, 0, 16, 
    0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 44, 0, 20, 7.5, 
    27.5, 12), Juncus_squarrosus = c(68L, 56L, 0L, 44L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 96L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hylocomium_splendens = c(21.6, 32.8, 0.8, 
    28, 0, 0, 68, 56, 0, 16, 24, 0, 8, 8, 0, 12, 12, 0, 0, 4, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), Rhytidiadelphus_loreus = c(70.4, 40, 32.8, 32, 
    48, 40, 56, 64, 76, 12, 52, 40, 0, 24, 0, 8, 24, 24, 0, 44, 
    12, 1, 3, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L
))
```

This is the code I've used to run the NMDS and produce the spider graph plot in `ggplot2`.

```
#subset the dataframe on which to base the ordination: the species data (dataframe 1)
data_1 <- dataNMDS[,9:17]

#Identify the columns that contains the descriptive/environmental data (dataframe 2)
data_2 <- dataNMDS[,2:8]


#ordination by NMDS
NMDS <- metaMDS(data_1, distance = "bray", k = 2)
stressplot(NMDS)


#########################
#Data visualisation


#Extract the axes scores
datascores <- as.data.frame(scores(NMDS))  #extract the site scores

#Add/calculate spider diagram
scores <- cbind(as.data.frame(datascores), Habitat = data_2$Plot_gradient)
centroids <- aggregate(cbind(NMDS1, NMDS2) ~ Habitat, data = scores, FUN = mean)
seg <- merge(scores, setNames(centroids, c('Habitat','oNMDS1','oNMDS2')),
             by = 'Habitat', sort = FALSE)

#NMDS spider graph plot
ggplot(scores, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, colour = Habitat)) +
  geom_segment(data = seg,
               mapping = aes(xend = oNMDS1, yend = oNMDS2)) + # add spiders
  geom_point(data = centroids, size = 4) +                    # add centroids
  geom_point() +                                              
  coord_fixed()+                                              
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="right",legend.text=element_text(size=10),legend.direction='vertical')
```

This code produces this image below...

[image]

However, I'd like to change the colour of the habitat types showing a gradient from Grassland to heath.

I've tried things like...

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen" , "green4" , "green3" , "green2", "orangered" , "orangered2" , "orangered3" , "orangered4"),
                    breaks = c("Grassland","EGA","EGB","EGC","EHC","EHB","EHA","Heath"))
```

But my limited R skill causes me to fail though, from what I can tell it seems to relate to the `aes (colour = Habitat)`.

I've also tried to add the contours of the Shannon diversity which I've calculated with...
`ordisurf(NMDS, diversity(data_1), add = T)`
and

```
shannon <- ordisurf(NMDS, diversity(data_1), add = T)
shannoncurve <- ordisurfgrid.long(shannon)
+ geom_contour(data=shannoncurve,aes(x=x, y=y, z=z))
```

Though I can't get that to work either.

Sorry for the incredibly long-winded and probably simple question but any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Does replacing `scale_fill_manual()` with `scale_colour_manual()` help?

Comment: @teunbrand Yes, that's worked for the colour change thank you! Such a simple fix and very much appreciated.

Comment: Always useful to answer questions as Answers that one or the other of you put up and accept, completing the virtuous circle, as answers in comments tend to get lost, even to interesting questions,